# After Beamer upgrade: \ifx\insertsection\empty yields FALSE as soon as \part defined?

Tags: beamer

## Problem statement

For many years, I used the following code to automatically insert the title of the current `\section` as the Beamer frame title, unless no section has yet been defined - in which case the title of the current `\part` should be used instead.

```
\newcommand{\autoframetitle}{%
  \ifx\insertsection\empty%
    \insertpart%
  \else%
    \insertsection%
  \fi%
}%
```

With a recent Beamer upgrade (most likely the one to version 3.50), the above code ceased to work in situations where a `\part` but no `\section` has been defined. This will cause the above test to end up in the `\else` branch, and an (empty) section title will therefore be printed instead of the expected part title.

I am looking for a way to restore the original intended behavior.

## Minimal (non-)working example (MWE)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\autoframetitle}{%
  \ifx\insertsection\empty%
    \insertpart%
  \else%
    \insertsection%
  \fi%
}%  

\begin{document}

\part{Part title}

\begin{frame}{\autoframetitle}%
   TODO: This slide should print the part title, but instead prints the (still empty) section title.
\end{frame}

\section{Section title}

\begin{frame}{\autoframetitle}%
  This slide prints (as expected) the (now no longer empty) section title.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Issue seems to be related to presence of `\part{}`

The following second MWE demonstrates that the `\ifx\insertsection\empty` statement above appears to yield `FALSE` as soon as a `\part` is defined. If one takes out the `\part` definition, the test yields `TRUE` as expected.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\autoframetitle}{%
  \ifx\insertsection\empty%
    Neither part nor section defined
  \else%
    \insertsection%
  \fi%
}%  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\autoframetitle}%
  This slide correctly prints "Neither part nor section defined" fallback text.
\end{frame}

\section{Section title}

\begin{frame}{\autoframetitle}%
  This slide prints (as expected) the (now no longer empty) section title.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As beamer automatically loads etoolbox here's a simple alternative `\newcommand{\autoframetitle}{%
 \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\insertsection}{%
    \insertpart%
  }{%
    \insertsection%
  }%
}%  `, but unfortunately I cannot explain the change.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tested this and it works flawlessly. If only there was a way to accept both yours and David's answer... But since your comment contains a viable solution, I'll accept it if you write it up as an actual answer (unless an even simpler solution surfaces in the meantime).

Comment: As your question does not seem to ask for a solution, but for an explanation, I think you should accept David's answer.

Comment: That's a fair point, but is a flaw of the original question that I will address by editing it.

Comment: Just replace `\empty` by `\protectedempty` in your code having done once `\protected\def\protectedempty{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an explanation (David gave one), but a different approach which bases on beamer loading `etoolbox` by default. Hence you can replace your code with

```
\newcommand{\autoframetitle}{%
  \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\insertsection}{%
    \insertpart%
  }{%
    \insertsection%
  }%
}%
```

which will not show the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`\part` defines `\insertsection` by

```
\protected\def\insertsection{}
```

so it's empty but not `\ifx` equal to `\empty` which is defined by

```
\def\empty{}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for explaining the source of this problem! I guess my question than is which other test could restore the original behavior effectively? Perhaps TeXnician's one above? Any alternatives that do not rely on etoolbox?

Comment: @FlorianH.  `\if|\insertsection|`  perhaps which if `\insertsection` expands to nothing is `\if||` which is true (assume `\insertsection` never starts with `|`)

Answer (score 3):

A test for emptiness can be

```
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\insertsection}\relax
  <code when the expansion of \insertsection is empty>
\else
  <code when the expansion of \insertsection is not empty>
\fi
```

This will expand `\insertsection` once before applying `\detokenize`, so the nature of the tokens in the expansion of `\insertsection` is unimportant.